# spring scheduledtask cron expressions

Tags: java, spring, cron

I'm not sure if my cron expressions are correct and the use of '?' is a little bit confusing. (spring ScheduledTask)

These expressions I have:

1) Execute every 0, 15, 30, 45 second:

```
*/15 * * * * *
```

2) Execute every minute:

```
0 * * * * *
```

3) Execute every day at 23:59:59:

```
59 59 23 * * ?
```

Are my expressions correct?

1 and 2 seems to work. For 3 I have to wait.

How do I use the question mark?

Comment: yes your third expression is correct, moreover you can verify your expression on http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron expression is represented by six fields:

1.Seconds

2.Minutes

3.Hours

4.Day-of-Month

5.Month

6.Day-of-Week

7.Year (optional field)

**? ("no specific value")** - useful when you need to specify something in one of the two fields in which the character is allowed, but not the other. For example, if I want my trigger to fire on a particular day of the month (say, the 10th), but don't care what day of the week that happens to be, I would put "10" in the day-of-month field, and "?" in the day-of-week field.

**In simple words '?' means every day(Daily)**.